# Nao consigo carregar um tema no Wordpress

Tags: php

Estou tentando carregar um tema que comprei para o Wordpress e a seguinte frase aparece:

> (Warning: POST Content-Length of 29037349 bytes exceeds the limit of
>   8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0)

Já modifiquei o php.ini e não aconteceu nada.

Comment: Além de alterar o php.ini, você vai precisar reiniciar o servidor

Comment: Boa noite Denis. Já reiniciei o servidor ao fazer tal processo. Uso o xampp, e modifiquei o php.ini na pasta do xampp. Reiniciei o servidor e o erro continua.

Comment: Alterou tanto `upload_max_filesize` quanto `post_max_size`? Se sim, para quais valores?